# how can i insert a image in swing JList menu?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

this is my code:

```
URL imageUrl = status.getUser().getProfileImageURL();
ImageIcon tivitImage = new ImageIcon(imageUrl);
listModel.addElement(tivitImage.getImage());  // maybe this part is wrong
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listModel.addElement(tivitImage.getImage()); // maybe this part is wrong
```

Yes, thats the problem. Just add the Icon to the ListModel (not the image). JList supports a default renderer for Icons.

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass [`JList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) or use your own [`ListCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html), as it is shown [in this article](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0203.html).

Another reading: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JList.html, towards the end, a jlist with country flags is explained.

Comment: You don't have to subclass JList though, you can just set the cell renderer via jList.setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);